# how do I actually display a variable in SwiftUI to the end user

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is the code I have right now

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var myint = (10)
    var x1 = Int.random(in: 1..<1000)
    
    var body: some View {
```

I know how to display strings, however I just can't figure out how to display the INT variable value. The print function is for the console, but I want something that displays it, any idea?

Comment: can you be more clear? Are you facing any compiler error? Can you share minimum reproducible code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your `Int` to a `String` value

```
Text(x1.description)

Text(String(x1))

Text("\(x1)")
```

Comment: Did you put it in a Text? I assumed you knew that since you said that you knew how to do that.

Comment: It worked, I had some other errors with my brackets that were breaking. So any of the 3 work it seems, is there any benefit to using to either or? It seems that the middle one is the easiest to remember for me

Comment: I prefer the third because you can put other strings in it. It seems more flexible for me but it is a matter of preference. If it worked can you click the check mark? So the answer is accepted.

Comment: Using a NumberFormatter is another option but maybe more relevant for larger values